# How to linearize a constraint with a maximum or minimum in the right-hand-side?

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

Suppose we have three variables, $x, y, z \in \mathbb R$. How can we linearize constraints with the following structure?

$$z \geq \min(x, y)$$
$$z \leq \max(x, y)$$

Comment: are the constraints both active? Or do you want to have them independently?

Comment: I meant both constraint independently. However there is already an answer that considers them simultaneously. Tomorrow I'll adjust this question to be  the version for both constraints simultaneously and I will make a new question that considers them independently.

Comment: Oops, sorry I misunderstood the original question!

Comment: Currently, I am typing the question with both constraints independently, but are the answers to both versions not too similar to deserve a separate question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically the condition is saying, $z$ must be between $x$ and $y$, regardless of whether $x \le y$ or $y \le x$.

Here's a method that involves a new binary variable and a big-$M$.

Let $w$ a binary variable that equals 1 if $x < y$:
$$\begin{align}
y - x & \le Mw \\
x - y & \le M(1-w) 
\end{align}$$
So, if $x < y$ then $w$ must equal 1; if $x > y$ then $w$ must equal 0; and if $x=y$ then $w$ could be either.

Now add the following constraints:
$$\begin{align}
z & \ge y - Mw \\
z & \le x + Mw \\
z & \ge x - M(1-w) \\
z & \le y + M(1-w)
\end{align}$$
In other words:

- If $x < y$ ($w=1$), then $z$ must be $\ge x$ and $\le y$
- If $x > y$ ($w=0$), then $z$ must be $\ge y$ and $\le x$
- If $x=y$, then we don't know what $w$ equals, but either way, the constraints amount to $z = x = y$.