# defining Mixed integer linear inequalities for a set of variables

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, modeling, linearization, big-m

The problem is described as follows:
considering $n$ variables which are continuous and bounded such that 
$$L_i \le x_i \le U_i\quad \forall i=1,2,\dots,n.$$

How can i define a set of mixed integer linear inequalities such that the feasible solution will be

$$y = \max(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n).$$

I am not certain of my approach but this is what i have so far

constraint 1: $y \ge x_i$;

constraint 2: $y \ge x_i + (U_i-L_i)w$;

where $w\in\{0,1\}$

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/110/71

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constraint 1 is fine.  It imposes $y \ge \max(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.  For constraint 2, you need to reverse the inequality and also introduce binary variable $w_i$ (with the interpretation that $w_i=1$ implies that $x_i$ is the maximum):
$$y \le x_i + M_i (1 - w_i).$$
We want the constraint to be redundant if $w_i = 0$, so take $M_i = \max(U_1,\dots,U_n) - L_i$.

Now also impose $$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1.$$  (Alternatively, you can relax this to $\ge 1$.)

If $n=2$, this formulation reduces to the one given [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-to-formulate-maximum-function-in-a-constraint).